# Find the maximal weighted independent set of a special graph .

Tags: graph-theory

Given a graph $G=${$V,E$} where each node has a cost associated with it , find the [maximal weighted independent set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_(graph_theory)#Finding_independent_sets) of this graph .
 
$|V| <= 10^5$ and $|V| <= |E| <= |V| + 5$ .
|V| denotes the number of vertices . 
|E| denotes the number of edges .
I don't know how to take advantage of the fact that $|V| <= |E| <= |V| + 5 .$

Comment: maximal independent set will be equal to complement of min vertex cover .

Comment: I just need to find the weight of the maximal independent set . (dont need to find the actual set)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

- Suppose that you are given a graph $G$ which is a tree, can you find maximum-weight independent set in $G$?
- How can you reduce your graph to a set of forrests, such that, one of them has to contain the maximum weight independent set?

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$